# Arduino GPS and GPRS Shield stop working when stored data to database

Tags: database, gps, arduino, gprs

i'm trying to make a live tracking for car. i used GPS Shield and GPRS Shield. it works to get GPS latitude and longatitude, and it works to store the data to my database. But, the problem is, when it get the gps coordinates, then my GPS Shield Turning off automatically when the GPRS Shield finished store the data in my database.

I use GPS/GSM/GPRS Shield from DFRobotcan and GPRS Shield from SeedStudio. i can't used my GPRS from DFRobot because i can't get signal. it's not the problem for me.

the problem is why my GPS shield shuting down when the GPRS Shield done to store the data? anyone help me
Here's my amateur code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <String.h>
double lati, longati, latitudefix, longatitudefix;
String latu, longatu, latdir, londir, latitudebener, longatitudebener;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8);
String id="1310220001";

void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(19200); // the GPRS baud rate
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);//The default digital driver pins for the GSM and GPS mode
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  delay(1500);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);//Enable GSM mode
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);//Disable GPS mode
  delay(2000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(5000);//GPS ready

  Serial.println("AT");  
  delay(2000);
  //turn on GPS power supply
  Serial.println("AT+CGPSPWR=1");
  delay(1000);
  //reset GPS in autonomy mode
  Serial.println("AT+CGPSRST=1");
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(4,LOW);//Enable GPS mode
  digitalWrite(3,HIGH);//Disable GSM mode
  delay(2000);

  Serial.println("$GPGGA statement information: ");
}
void loop()
{
  while(1)
  {
  Serial.print("UTC:");
  UTC();
  Serial.print("Lat:");
  latitude();
  Serial.print("Dir:");
  lat_dir();
  Serial.print("Lon:");
  longitude();
  Serial.print("Dir:");
  lon_dir();
  Serial.print("Alt:");
  altitude();
  convert();
  //Serial.println(latitudebener);
  //Serial.println(longatitudebener);
  Serial.println(' ');
  Serial.println(' ');


  if(latitudebener!="0.00000"&&longatitudebener!="0.00000"){
    sendlocation();
  }
  else{
  };
  }
}


void convert(){
  char bufferlat[20];
  latitudebener=dtostrf(latitudefix,5,5,bufferlat);
  char bufferlon[20];
  longatitudebener=dtostrf(longatitudefix,5,5,bufferlon);
}

void sendlocation(){
  mySerial.println("AT+CSQ");
  delay(100);

  mySerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(100);

  mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");//setting the SAPBR, the connection type is using gprs
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"AXIS\"");//setting the APN, the second need you fill in your local apn server
  delay(4000);

  mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");//setting the SAPBR, for detail you can refer to the AT command mamual
  delay(2000);;

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT"); //init the HTTP request
  delay(2000); 

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"www.hamasa.cu.cc/editlocation.php?id="+id+"&latitude="+latitudebener+"&longatitude="+longatitudebener+"&latdir="+latdir+"&londir="+londir+"\"");
  delay(2000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");//submit the request 
  Serial.println("8");
  delay(5000);//the delay is very important, the delay time is base on the return from the website, if the return datas are very large, the time required longer.

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD");// read the data from the website you access
  delay(300);

  mySerial.println("");
  delay(100);
}

//void sms()
//{
//  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1\r"); //Because we want to send the SMS in text mode
//  delay(100);
//  ShowSerialData();
//  mySerial.println("AT + CMGS = \"+6283815535385\"");//send sms message, 
//  //be careful need to add a country code before the cellphone number
//
//  delay(100);
//  ShowSerialData();
//  mySerial.println("bisa bil, latitudenya:"+latitudebener+""+latdir+", terus longatitudenya:"+longatitudebener+""+londir);//the content of the message
//  delay(100);
//  ShowSerialData();
//  mySerial.println((char)26);//the ASCII code of the ctrl+z is 26
//  delay(100);
//  ShowSerialData();
//  mySerial.println();
//  ShowSerialData();
//}
void ShowSerialData()
{
  while(mySerial.available()!=0)
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}

double Datatransfer(char *data_buf,char num)//convert the data to the float type
{                                           //*data_buf：the data array                                      
  double temp=0.0;                           //the number of the right of a decimal point
  unsigned char i,j;

  if(data_buf[0]=='-')
  {
    i=1;
    //process the data array
    while(data_buf[i]!='.')
      temp=temp*10+(data_buf[i++]-0x30);
    for(j=0;j<num;j++)
      temp=temp*10+(data_buf[++i]-0x30);
    //convert the int type to the float type
    for(j=0;j<num;j++)
      temp=temp/10;
    //convert to the negative numbe
    temp=0-temp;
  }
  else//for the positive number
  {
    i=0;
    while(data_buf[i]!='.')
      temp=temp*10+(data_buf[i++]-0x30);
    for(j=0;j<num;j++)
      temp=temp*10+(data_buf[++i]-0x30);
    for(j=0;j<num;j++)
      temp=temp/10 ;
  }
  return temp;
}

char ID()//Match the ID commands
{
  char i=0;
  char value[6]={
    '$','G','P','G','G','A'            };//match the gps protocol
  char val[6]={
    '0','0','0','0','0','0'            };

  while(1)
  {
    if(Serial.available())
    {
      val[i] = Serial.read();//get the data from the serial interface
      if(val[i]==value[i]) //Match the protocol
      {   
        i++;
        if(i==6)
        {
          i=0;
          return 1;//break out after get the command
        }
      }
      else
        i=0;
    }
  }
}

void comma(char num)//get ','
{  
  char val;
  char count=0;//count the number of ','

  while(1)
  {
    if(Serial.available())
    {
      val = Serial.read();
      if(val==',')
        count++;
    }
    if(count==num)//if the command is right, run return
      return;
  }

}
void UTC()//get the UTC data -- the time
{
  char i;
  char time[9]={
    '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'
  };
  double t=0.0;

  if( ID())//check ID
  {
    comma(1);//remove 1 ','
    //get the datas after headers
    while(1)
    {
      if(Serial.available())
      {
        time[i] = Serial.read();
        i++;
      }
      if(i==9)
      {
        i=0;
        t=Datatransfer(time,2);//convert data
        t=t+70000.00;//convert to the chinese time GMT+8 Time zone
        Serial.println(t);//Print data
        return;
      } 
    }
  }
}
void latitude()//get latitude
{
  char i;
  char lat[10]={
    '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};


  if( ID())
  {
    comma(2);
    while(1)
    {
      if(Serial.available())
      {
        lat[i] = Serial.read();
        i++;
      }
      if(i==10)
      {
        i=0;
        char buzz[20];
        lati=Datatransfer(lat,5);
        latu=dtostrf(lati,5,5,buzz);
        String latijam=latu.substring(0,1);
        String latimin=latu.substring(1,3);
        String latidet=latu.substring(4,9);
        double latijamd = latijam.toInt();
        double latimind = latimin.toInt();
        double latidetd = latidet.toInt();
        double latmin = latimind+(latidetd*0.00001);
        latitudefix= latijamd+(latmin/60);
        Serial.println(latitudefix,5); 
        return;
      } 
    }
  }
}
void lat_dir()//get dimensions
{
  char i=0,val;

  if( ID())
  {
    comma(3);
    while(1)
    {
      if(Serial.available())
      {
        val = Serial.read();
        latdir=String(val);
        Serial.print(latdir);
        Serial.println();
        i++;
      }
      if(i==1)
      {
        i=0;
        return;
      } 
    }
  }
}
void longitude()//get longitude
{
  char i;
  char lon[11]={
    '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'      };

  if( ID())
  {
    comma(4);
    while(1)
    {
      if(Serial.available())
      {
        lon[i] = Serial.read();
        i++;
      }
      if(i==11)
      {
        i=0;
        //Serial.println(Datatransfer(lon,5),5);
        char buffer[20];
        longati=Datatransfer(lon,5);
        longatu=dtostrf(longati,5,5,buffer);
        String longatijam=longatu.substring(0,3);
        String longatimin=longatu.substring(3,5);
        String longatidet=longatu.substring(6,11);
        double longatijamd = longatijam.toInt();
        double longatimind = longatimin.toInt();
        double longatidetd = longatidet.toInt();
        double longmin = longatimind+(longatidetd*0.00001);
        longatitudefix= longatijamd+(longmin/60);
        Serial.println(longatitudefix,5);
        return;
      } 
    }
  }
}
void lon_dir()//get direction data
{
  char i=0,val;

  if( ID())
  {
    comma(5);
    while(1)
    {
      if(Serial.available())
      {

        val = Serial.read();
        londir=String(val);
        Serial.print(londir);
        Serial.println();
        i++;
      }
      if(i==1)
      {
        i=0;
        return;
      } 
    }
  }
}

void altitude()//get altitude data
{
  char i,flag=0;
  char alt[8]={
    '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'
  };

  if( ID())
  {
    comma(9);
    while(1)
    {
      if(Serial.available())
      {
        alt[i] = Serial.read();
        if(alt[i]==',')
          flag=1;
        else
          i++;
      }
      if(flag)
      {
        i=0;
        Serial.println(Datatransfer(alt,1),1);//print altitude data
        return;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it take to get it to start again?  Will reseting the Arduino do it, or do you have to power cycle?  If resetting the Arduino does it, your code may be getting stuck...

Comment: yes, resetting the arduinoe can make it start again. is there a code that make my program getting stuck? i have try to change the methode from store to database with sending sms. it work. but why store to database can make my code stuck? i have check the pin in arduino. there is no conflict there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use external power. is that works?

Answer (score 0):

actually it should be :

```
digitalWrite(3,LOW);//Enable GSM mode
digitalWrite(4,HIGH);//Disable GPS mode
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be a software serial port conflict, because `GPS` and `GSM` shields both use serial ports. In your case you have coupled shields. While receiving a `GPS` signal, `GSM` is switched off, and when a signal is acquired, the `GPS` turns off and `GSM` begin to work.